# How to scanf only integer and repeat reading if the user enters non-numeric characters?

Tags: c, validation, user-input

Here is some C code trying simply to prevent the user from typing a character or an integer less than 0 or more than 23.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *input;
    char *iPtr;
    int count = 0;
    int rows;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    rows = strtol(input, &iPtr, 0);
    while( *iPtr != '\0') // Check if any character has been inserted
    {
        printf("Enter an integer between 1 and 23: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
    }
    while(0 < rows && rows < 24) // check if the user input is within the boundaries
    {
        printf("Select an integer from 1 to 23: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
    }  
    while (count != rows)  
    {  
        /* Do some stuff */  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

I made it halfway through and a small push up will be appreciated.

Comment: I've noticed an obvious problem in third scanf command, it should be scanf("%i", &rows); but still the code is broken :(

Comment: Have you considered allocating memory for those `scanf` calls? as it stands now, they're reading into the address being held in an uninitialized pointer (`input`) which is undefined behavior. I'm pretty sure if its `int` values your looking for you should be using `%d` and scanning into the address of an `int` variable. Also, check the return values of your `scanf` calls, which will tell you how many fields were *successfully* obtained.

Comment: I changed the 'input' pointer into an array 'char input[100];'

Comment: Why are you reading this into a text buffer *at all* ?? You're looking for an integer value in `[0..23]` correct? Just scan to an `int` and check to for a successful parse and a value in-range, unless there is some special characters you're also interested in getting. Perhaps reading more about [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) may be warranted?

Comment: there are two types of inputs I do not want the user to enter, characters and outrange integers and this is why I used text buffer.

Comment: @AbdulelahAl-Jeffery: in this case you can use `scanf("%d")` to get your integer and if the user enter no numeric characters then you can scanf with `scanf("%s)` again in order to free your `stdin` before the next `scanf("%d")`. Refer to my anwer I updated it with this

Comment: @AbdulelahAl-Jeffery: enter some example of your inputs

Comment: remove the `while (count != rows);`. this is blocking your program

Comment: Enter an integer from 1 to 23: 123asd (invalid), erwea(invalid), -823 (invalid), 30 (invalid), 8 (valid)

Comment: @AbdulelahAl-Jeffery: I updated the code in my answer. and I tested it and it works

Comment: Yes that works but it seems like if there is something wrong here scanf("%[^\n]", input)?! as if the editor expect something after % symbol?!!! would you explain this pice only please. thank you (Jazak Allah Keer).

Comment: `"%[^\n]"` means: expecting string input containing what ever charcters except `"\n"` (newline). That means read and clean the whole content of the stdin (beraka Allah fik)

Comment: @AbdulelahAl-Jeffery I used a `clean_stdin` function instead of the `scanf("%[^\n]",input)` inorder to avoid buffer overflow of `input`. Please refer to the answer to see the update

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL OK, now it becomes clearer to me. One thing I noticed was you got ride of `input` array and replace it with `c` of char type?! is it because we want to save as much memory as possible?

Comment: if I were you, I won't put more than three conditions in `while` loop ; I would rather break it down into more than one and print the appropriate message that has to do with the invalid user-input. I think this will improve the code readability as will as user experience. you may correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you brother.

Comment: @AbdulelahAl-Jeffery There is a minor risk in the `scanf("%[^\n]", input)` which is the case if the user enter a string bigger than the input buffer size so you will get a buffer overflow. So that's why I replaced this by a `while` loop and `getchar()`.  `getchar()` allows to read from stdin 1 character. and if you repeated the `getchar()` many times until you get `\n` you will get the stdin cleaned

Comment: @AbdulelahAl-Jeffery  Concerning the conditions of the `while` loop. I updated my answer for more explanation. Please refer to the answer. You are welcome Brother

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `scanf("%d",&rows)` instead of `scanf("%s",input)`

This allow you to get direcly the integer value from stdin without need to convert to int.

If the user enter a string containing a non numeric characters then you have to clean your stdin before the next `scanf("%d",&rows)`.

your code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

int clean_stdin()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        ;
    return 1;
}

int main(void)  
{ 
    int rows =0;  
    char c;
    do
    {  
        printf("\nEnter an integer from 1 to 23: ");
  
    } while (((scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin()) || rows<1 || rows>23);

    return 0;  
}
```

**Explanation**

1)

```
scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)
```

This means expecting from the user input an integer and close to it a non numeric character.

***Example1:*** If the user enter `aaddk` and then `ENTER`, the scanf will return 0. Nothing capted

***Example2:*** If the user enter `45` and then `ENTER`, the scanf will return 2 (2 elements are capted). Here `%d` is capting `45` and `%c` is capting `\n`

***Example3:*** If the user enter `45aaadd` and then `ENTER`, the scanf will return 2 (2 elements are capted). Here `%d` is capting `45` and `%c` is capting `a`

2)

```
(scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n')
```

***In the example1:*** this condition is `TRUE` because scanf return `0` (`!=2`)

***In the example2:*** this condition is `FALSE` because scanf return `2` and `c == '\n'`

***In the example3:*** this condition is `TRUE` because scanf return `2` and `c == 'a' (!='\n')`

3)

```
((scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin())
```

`clean_stdin()` is always `TRUE` because the function return always `1`

***In the example1:***  The `(scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n')` is `TRUE` so the condition after the `&&` should be checked so the `clean_stdin()` will be executed and the whole condition is `TRUE`

***In the example2:*** The `(scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n')` is `FALSE` so the condition after the `&&` will not checked (because what ever its result is the whole condition will be `FALSE` ) so the `clean_stdin()` will not be executed and the whole condition is `FALSE`

***In the example3:***  The `(scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n')` is `TRUE` so the condition after the `&&` should be checked so the `clean_stdin()` will be executed and the whole condition is `TRUE`

So you can remark that `clean_stdin()` will be executed only if the user enter a string containing non numeric character.

And this condition `((scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin())` will return `FALSE` only if the user enter an `integer` and nothing else

And if the condition `((scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin())` is `FALSE` and the `integer` is between and `1` and `23` then the `while` loop will break else the `while` loop will continue

Comment: For starters, there is no check to see if whatever `scanf()` did (if anything) actually populated `rows`. Therefore you're potentially checking an indeterminate value. you should at least validate that `scanf()` returned 1.

Comment: I used the `clean_stdin` function instead of the `scanf("%[^\n]",input)` inorder to avoid buffer overflow of `input`

Comment: can you make this also repeat when the user only presses enter?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char str[100];
    int num;
    while(1) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%[^0-9]%d",str,&num);
        printf("You entered the number %d\n",num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`%[^0-9]` in `scanf()` gobbles up all that is not between `0` and `9`. Basically it cleans the input stream of non-digits and puts it in `str`. Well, the length of non-digit sequence is limited to 100. The following `%d` selects only integers in the input stream and places it in `num`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that reads an integer between 1 and 23 or returns 0 if non-int

e.g.

```
int getInt()
{
  int n = 0;
  char buffer[128];
  fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
  n = atoi(buffer); 
  return ( n > 23 || n < 1 ) ? 0 : n;
}
```

Comment: What about the characters? I'm not expecting the user to input a string or an integer outside the range.

Comment: it is always good to presume nothing about what is written by a user.

Answer (score 1):

```
char check1[10], check2[10];
int foo;

do{
  printf(">> ");
  scanf(" %s", check1);
  foo = strtol(check1, NULL, 10); // convert the string to decimal number
  sprintf(check2, "%d", foo); // re-convert "foo" to string for comparison
} while (!(strcmp(check1, check2) == 0 && 0 < foo && foo < 24)); // repeat if the input is not number
```

If the input is number, you can use `foo` as your input.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to repeat your call to `strtol` inside your loops where you are asking the user to try again. In fact, if you make the loop a `do { ... } while(...);` instead of while, you don't get a the same sort of repeat things twice behaviour.

You should also format your code so that it's possible to see where the code is inside a loop and not.

Answer (score -1):

this is a reply to
[prevent users from entering wrong data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104013/prevent-users-from-entering-wrong-data-types)

If you're dealing with just numbers
declare

char catchpan;

and then right after your scanf for a number input
put

scanf("%c", &catchpan);

its not a complete fix but if you have code that handles out of bounds stuff (assuming zero isn't a part of the bounds) it'll clear right up.

it ain't perfect and it ain't the general solution.

Comment: So you're answering a closed question on another question? That is - well - simply not the right way to do it. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32510098)