# prevent users from entering wrong data types

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to scanf only integer and repeat reading if the user enter non numeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099473/how-to-scanf-only-integer-and-repeat-reading-if-the-user-enter-non-numeric-chara)

Hi i'm new to c and i am writing a program that asks the user to enter an integer and if it does not match the criteria of being within a certain range, like lass than 20, but greater than 5. It asks the user to enter the value again.

However i wondered what would happen if i entered a character, and well it creates an infinite loop.

So i want to know is there a way or a specific function that will check the entered value to see if it is the correct data type. And i not repromts the user.

Comment: Read a line with `fgets`, parse it with `sscanf` and make your sanity test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read with `scanf("%d")` and if the user enter a string containing a non numeric character then you have to clean the stdin buffer  before reading again with `scanf("%d")`.

when you clean the stdin, you will stop the infinite loop

Use the following function to clean your stdin

```
int clean_stdin()
{
    while (getchar()!='\n');
    return 1;
}
```

And The read of your integer from stdin could be done in this way:

```
char c;
do
{  
    printf("\nEnter an integer from 5 to 20: ");

} while (((scanf("%d%c", &rows, &c)!=2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin()) || rows<5 || rows>20);
```

Comment: That will of course overflow if `input` isn't long enough to hold the entire input. Better to use fgets() and sscanf() or something like that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I added a function which clean stdin buffer instead of using `scanf("%[^\n]", input)`. Code updated. Thank you for the remark

Comment: I would prefer getchar() - and check for eof!

Comment: why check eof??? the user is going to enter string (which should be integer) and if is integer than stop otherwise repeat reading. so the stop condition of reading could be classic character which is the famous "\n"

Comment: And if the user presses CTRL-Z (on a Windows system) or CTRL-D (Linux,Unix,OSX Mac), what happens. Is it a good idea to lock up the system at that point? Or if the input is coming from a file via a redirection. Just because the user uses a file for input doesn't mean it's not got errors!

Comment: @MOHAMED -- for robustness the loop in `clean_stdin` should terminate on either `\n` or `EOF` because `getchar` can return `EOF` in a number of circumstances: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { continue; }`. Note that once `getchar` returns `EOF`, subsequent calls to `getchar` will also return `EOF` and failing to test for this condition will then lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 6):

Many have tried, but there has so far not been any success in making computers that have control over the user's brain to prevent the user from pressing the wrong (kind of) buttons at times... ;)

There are two commonly accepted solutions to solve this:

1. Write a direct input function that reads with "no echo", and discards [possibly with some message being displayed] bad input, and specific input functions that "know" what is valid input.
2. Use standard functions to read the input as a text string, and then (attempt to) convert/validate the string input to number or whatever. Here, if conversion/validation fails, you print some message and asks the user to try again.

Answer (score 5):

To counter this possibility, you must scan in your input as text, and then do the sanity testing on your own.

Comment: what exactly is sanity testing? As i said before i'm very new to c programming.

Comment: "Sanity testing" is a colloquial term for tests to make sure that some simple, basic conditions are true -- like that the user hasn't entered a string of letters when you requested numbers, for example.

Answer (score 2):

A common method is to read the input as text, then convert to the target type using a library function like `strtol` or `strtod`.  Both of those functions also allow you to detect bad input.

Here's one approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  char instr[12];
  int  value;
  char *chk;

  /**
   * Make sure read is successful
   */
  errno = 0;
  if (!fgets(instr, sizeof instr, stdin))
  {
    perror("Unable to read input string");
    exit(-1);
  }

  /**
   * Make sure user didn't enter more characters
   * than we're prepared to handle.
   */
  if (!strchr(instr,'\n'))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input too long for buffer, discarding...\n");
    while (!strchr(instr,'\n'))
      fgets(instr, sizeof instr, stdin);
     exit(-1);
  }
  else
  {
    *strchr(instr,'\n') = 0;
  }


  /**
   * Convert text to decimal integer using strtol
   */
  value = (int) strtol(instr, &chk, 10);
  if (!isspace(*chk) && *chk != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", instr);
    fprintf(stderr, "%*s^\n", (int)(chk - instr), " ");
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid character detected in input string\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  printf("Converted input value is %d\n", value);
  return 0;
}
```

So, assuming you don't have a read error and that the user didn't enter an obnoxiously long input, you use `strtod` to convert the text string to the corresponding integer value.  `chk` will be set to point to the first character that isn't part of a valid integer constant.  If that character isn't a whitespace character (`isspace(*chk)`) or the 0 terminator, then the input wasn't a valid integer string.  You can then throw it away and ask for a new input.

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions in the header `<ctype.h>` in C..

`isalpha()` is used to check whether the entered input is an alphabet or not..

you can take the input in a string and check each character whether it is alphabet or digit.. keep it in a loop to check it and ask the user to re-enter if the given input is not valid one..

`isdigit()` is used to check whether the given input is a digit or not..

```
int is_alpha(char *s)
{
    while(*s) {
      if(isalpha(*s))
            s++;
        else 
            return 0;
    }

        return 1; 
   }
```

The above function checks whether the input entered are all alphabets or not.. I am returning '0' if the condition is failed and '1' if the condition is false..

Collect the return value in the main function and check..

Comment: i can post you an example if you still did not understand

Comment: Why check every character if you can check the whole string? (and you cand edit your answer instead of adding comments :) )

Comment: I agree with effeffe - it's much better to check the entire input field in one call. What if someone enters 999999999999999999999999999 as an integer? That's all digits, but it sure isn't going to fit in a regular 32-bit integer. Remember, users can be right nasty at times, if they are "the right kind" of user.

Comment: In your own is_alpha() function, why don't you use the isalpha() that you suggested earlier? And surely the `if (*s == '\0') return 1;` can be replaced by return 1, or is there some reason you believe that `while(*s)` may exit the loop with another value in `*s`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: if the input is 9999999999999999999, we can check the input with INT_MAX and INT_MIN after converting the string to integer using atoi()..  if the input exceeds the 32-bit integer, user can ask to re-enter the input..

Comment: Actually, no, if you convert with atoi(), you can't know what happens if the input is outside valid values. It may be truncated or you may get a saturated value. "There is no standard specification on what happens when the converted value would be out of the range of representable values by an int. See strtol for a more robust cross-platform alternative when this is a possibility." [from cplusplus atoi page]. Using strtol and friends will indeed allow such a compare.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Agree with you.. But i think we can write our own atoi function using long long datatype in place of int datatype.. I guess it works..

Answer (score -1):

There do exist functions which can check whether an entered number is an Integer or the entered character is actually between a-z.

But there are no functions that you can set for a specific range, you have to design your own.
A simple function can be like

```
int check(int a)
{
if(a>5 && a<20)
{
printf("Need a different Value");
}
}
```