# check50 error messages: On my Mario.c pset1 solution

Tags: cs50

> :( handles a height of 0 correctly   \ expected an exit code of 0, not output of "\n Please enter a positive integer valu..."
>
> :( rejects a non-numeric height of ""   \ expected output, not a prompt for input

https://sandbox.cs50.net/checks/5593ad8059ce4492804c07aff8e377eb

I think I should put part of my code too:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int clean_stdin()
    {
        while (getchar()!='\n');
        return 1;
    }                               //snippet gotten from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104013/prevent-users-from-entering-wrong-data-types
                                    

int main (void)
{
    int row, pyramid_height, space, hash;
    char c;             
    
    do
    {  
        printf("\n Please enter a positive integer value, less than 24 as the height: ");       

    }        
    while (((scanf("%i%c", &pyramid_height, &c) != 2 || c!='\n') && clean_stdin()) || pyramid_height < 1 || pyramid_height > 23);
                    //snippet gotten from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104013/prevent-users-from-entering-wrong-data-types
```

Please help:

Also, Is there an easier way to prevent users from entering wrong data?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this to ask the user for input

```
printf("Enter height < 23 and a non-negative number\n");
do{
    printf("Height: ");
    height = GetInt();    // ask user again until valid input is given
}while(height < 0 || height >23);
```

If you don't want to use GetInt() you can do this with scanf too. Just replace the GetInt line with `scanf("%d",&height);`. It'll work the same except when you enter a wrong number it'll yell at you by saying `Height:`
rather than `Retry:`.

And you should remove that clean_stdin function. That level of precision is not required in pset1.

Now the remaining part is the nested for loops which you've not provided in the question so, I am assuming that you have a problem there too since your program can't handle 0 properly.

Try something like this in place of the for loops.

```
for(int i=1; i<=height; i++){                    // i number of #s in each step
    for(int j=0; j<height-i; j++){            //print appropriate number of spaces
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(int k=0; k<=i; k++){                    //print #s
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");                               //change line
}
```

Comment: Thank you!...I had no problems with the for loops. Internet is expensive where i am so I  use an offline compiler Dev C++ and work without the cs50.h library. Didn't know the GetInt() function was that efficient.

Comment: You could accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @AdeyomolaAdebayo Also check the edits in the answer. If you don't wanna use cs50 library you can do that.