# How do i loop back to the start in c programme?

Tags: c, printf

How can I return back to the start of the programme if the user picks the option no?
please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int choice;
  printf("Are you done? 1 for Yes, 2 for No: ");
  scanf("%d",&choice);
  
  if (choice==1)
  {
      
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do it in a multiple ways, on of is to use `goto <label>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C programming - Loop until user inputs number scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25765040/c-programming-loop-until-user-inputs-number-scanf)

Comment: using goto makes code harder to read and is by convention not recommended, just put the code in a `while(1)` loop and break out of it when the user selects 1

Comment: @yvw please do not suggest using a `goto` for this. This is best solved using a loop, as in the linked duplicate.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with a proper use of goto.  It is often horribly misused, and misuse ought to be avoided.  But `goto start` would be better than convoluted logic in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using `while` loop:

```
int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        int choice;
        printf("Are you done? 1 for Yes, 2 for No: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`goto` is not recommended because it reduces code readability, but I still write it here because it can also solve your question.

```
int main()
{
$START:

    int choice;
    printf("Are you done? 1 for Yes, 2 for No: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 0) {
        goto $START;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Learn more about `goto`:

- [What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517746/13433323)
- [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307/13433323)

Comment: Note that if the input begins with a non-integer value (eg `a`), this will invoke undefined behavior since scanf will not write a value into `choice` and the condition is checking the value of an uninitialized variable.  You must *always* check the value returned by `scanf`.