# I need my program to tell the user "invalid entry..." if they dont input a correct variable type

Tags: c

The issue im having is when the user is prompted to enter a value if an invalid option is entered that is not of the type im scanning for i need the program to display a message "invalid entry" and break.

```
            if (UserInputTri == 'A')
            {
                system("cls");
                TriPermTotal = 0;
                printf("\nYou chose to calculate perimeter.\n\nPlease enter a value for side number 1: ");
                scanf("%f", &TriPerm1);
                printf("Please enter a value for side number 2: ");
                scanf("%f", &TriPerm2);
                printf("Please enter a value for side number 3: ");
                scanf("%f", &TriPerm3);
                TriPermTotal = TriPerm1 + TriPerm1 + TriPerm3;
                printf("\nThe total perimeter of the triangle is: %0.0f\n\n", TriPermTotal);
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            else
            {
                printf("\nNot a valid option, try again!\n\n");
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            }
```

If I type in a word instead of a number when the user is asked for side 1 it will loop forever.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099473/how-to-scanf-only-integer-and-repeat-reading-if-the-user-enter-non-numeric-chara

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scanf only integer and repeat reading if the user enter non numeric characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099473/how-to-scanf-only-integer-and-repeat-reading-if-the-user-enter-non-numeric-chara)